# Javascript error on mobile view

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I got a strange problem on my site [taikuri Kim Wist](http://www.kimwist.com) on mobile view. I don't know if the problem is on Apple devices, but with Samsung and Android devices it is definitely there.

When typing the root domain address, the page wont load and keeps jumping back and fort. Furthermore it jumps directly to another page [on my site](http://www.kimwist.com/taikuri.html) which is an inner page.

There is on line 109 of the index page a javascript file js/script.js 
If I remove this script, the problem goes away, but the script is needed to operate the middle (stellar) section of the page. I have not modified the script.js file in any way and there was no problem one week ago. I made a new footer to my page, but it should not generate an error like this.

If anyone knows why this occurs I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able eventually to find the error, which was inside script.js file.
I commented out  //window.location.href = $(this).attr("href"); on line 85.
This solved the problem and the page is now displaying correctly on Android devices.